# Android TYPE_STEP_COUNTER sensor does not work while screen off

Tags: android, pedometer

I'm developing an app to detect and count the steps. I used `TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR/COUNTER` sensors. Everything works fine but when the screen turns off, no more step detects. I tried to solve this problem by using

```
wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK,"MyWakelockTag");
```

and    `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` and foreground service, but the problem still remains. Also I do not want to use Google Fit API.
Any suggestion please?
Thanks in advance.